# SQL Server query

Tags: t-sql

All machines should have three groups(grp1,grp2,grp3)
but some have two groups and some might have all three and some might have 1 or zero.

I have data like this, I have two columns:

```
MachineName   GrpName
Machine1      grp1
Machine1      grp2
Machine1      grp3
Machine2      grp1
Machine2      grp2
Machine3      grp3
Machine4      grp2
Machine4      grp3
```

I am trying to write a query to see missing groups for all machines from the above data

So 
Machine1 has all three we can skip or say all three exist

```
MachineName   GrpName
Machine1      all three exist--if we can do this good if not fine we can just skip since it has all three.
Machin2       Grp3 missing
Machine3       Grp1 and Grp2 missing
Machine4       grp1 missing
```

Any help on this will be appreciated...

Comment: We can write a scalar UDF and apply that on group by output of table,to get data in required format.

Answer (score 3):

Group by `MachineName` and get the rows where there are less then 3 distinct values in `GrpName`.

To figure out what groups are missing you can use the table value constructor to include the group names you want to check and use `for xml` to build a string with the missing group names.

```
declare @T table
(
  MachineName varchar(10),
  GrpName varchar(10)
);

insert into @T values
('Machine1',      'grp1'),
('Machine1',      'grp2'),
('Machine1',      'grp3'),
('Machine2',      'grp1'),
('Machine2',      'grp1'),
('Machine2',      'grp2'),
('Machine3',      'grp3'),
('Machine3',      'grp3'),
('Machine4',      'grp2'),
('Machine4',      'grp3');

select T1.MachineName,
       (
       select G.Name+' '
       from (values('grp1'),('grp2'),('grp3')) as G(Name)
       where not exists (
                        select *
                        from @T as T2
                        where T1.MachineName = T2.MachineName and
                              G.Name = T2.GrpName
                        )
       for xml path('')     
       ) as MissingGroupNames
from @T as T1
group by T1.MachineName
having count(distinct T1.GrpName) < 3;
```

Result:

```
MachineName MissingGroupNames
----------- -----------------
Machine2    grp3 
Machine3    grp1 grp2 
Machine4    grp1
```

Comment: Appreciate your help! It works great. I am also trying to get machines that doesn't have all three groups.

Comment: @schinni9 Sorry, I don't understand what you want. This query **is** giving you the *"machines that doesn't have all three groups"*.

Answer (score 0):

written from the head, maybe this will help ya

```
-- extract group Names from table
with groups as (
select grpName 
from table
group by grpName
)
select maschineName, string_agg(grpName,',') as missingOnes -- here you need something mssql specific, haven't found any  
from table t
where not exists (
  select 1 from groups where groups.grpName = t.grpName
)
group by maschineName
```

if there no specific agg function for strings in mssql, you can remove the grouping. Maybe this is enough for your output format